# Javascript multiply function failed when together

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript function does not work when

```
function loadcontents(obj) {
  var params = $(obj).attr('href').split('?');
  $.getJSON(IVIDPLAY_BASE_DIR+'content/load2.php?'+params[1], function(json) { 
  if (json.returnval == 1) {
    $('#contents').fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).html('json.contents').fadeIn('slow'); });
  }
}
```

is trigger to replace this div:

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="{$content2.url}" onclick="return loadContent2(this, 'page', '2')">Click Here
    </a>
</div>
```

in another word, there is a function being refresh by the first function and it does not work, when the second one does work.

However! when

```
loadContent2(this, 'page', '2')
```

is replace or remove

```
loadContent2(this, "page", "2")
```

like so, the first function work, but not the second!

is there a way to by pass the quote issue? if it's a quote issue?

any help highly appreciated!

EDIT:

fire bug show no error, but it's clearly not working as logically should.

Comment: You have two different function names: `loadcontents` and `loadContent2`.

Comment: Looks like jQuery - if so, add the tag.

Comment: 1. it's support to have 2 different function.

Comment: 2. what tag(s) are you referring to?

Comment: 3. if you are just spamming comment, do it else where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well,

You need to use this:

```
loadContent2(this, \"page\", \"2\")
```

:)

Comment: it does not work, it just redirect the page instead of executing the javascript.

Comment: and refresh the same content without refreshing the whole page. i hope this make sense.

Comment: @Poppy: not sure what the return value is, but you may try this: onclick="loadContent2(this, 'page', '2'); return false;"

Comment: Lol, nvm all i got to do is add return false; Thank you Roberto!

Comment: lol, i did not know you reply untill after i add comment, but yes, you are dead on!

Comment: Pop no problemo~ Glad helps :)